# User Context in Django

Tags: django, authentication, django-context

I am having problems with user authentication for my django site.  I have a log-in screen that seems to work.  When the user clicks log-in, I call the `django.contrib.auth.login`  and it seems to work fine.  However on subsequent pages have no knowledge that there is a user logged in.   Example  `{% user.is_authenticated %}` is false.   There are also some menu functions that I want to be available for logged in users such as `my-account` and `logout`.   Those functions are not available, except on the log-in page.  Which is really strange.

This seems to be a user context problem.  But I'm not sure how I am supposed to be passing a context around to ensure that my login is stable.    `Does anyone know at could be going on here?  Any advice?`

---------part of base.html------------

```
<!--- The following doesn't register even though I know I'm authenticated -->
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <div id="menu">
            <ul>
             <li><a href="/clist">My Customers</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Customer Actions</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
{% endif %}
```

---------my views.py -----------------

```
# Should I be doing something to pass the user context here
def customer_list(request):
   customer_list = Customer.objects.all().order_by('lastName')[:5]
   c = Context({
      'customer_list': customer_list,
      })
   t = loader.get_template(template)
   return HttpResponse(t.render(cxt))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Django 1.3, you can use the [`render()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render) shortcut, which automatically includes `RequestContext` for you.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def customer_list(request):
   customer_list = Customer.objects.all().order_by('lastName')[:5]
   return render(request, "path_to/template.html",
                 {'customer_list': customer_list,})
```

In this case, you could go one step further, and use the generic [`ListView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.list.ListView):

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

class CustomerList(Listview):
    template_name = 'path_to/template.html'
    queryset = Customer.objects.all().order_by('lastName')[:5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext).

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel Suggested, use the RequestContext... or better, just use the [render_to_response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render_to_response) shortcut:

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def customer_list(request):
   customer_list = Customer.objects.all().order_by('lastName')[:5]
   return render_to_response(
         "path_to/template.html",
         {'customer_list':customer_list,}, 
         context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```